# "STS3 Webpage ID Duplication Check Not Functioning for Login and Membership: Need Help!"

Tags: java, spring, macos, sts

I'm practicing the process of creating a webpage with STS3, but the ID duplication check function doesn't work on the webpage for login and membership.

I'm creating a Spring legacy project with STS3 to practice creating web pages. In the Windows 10 environment, the login/logout is implemented properly, and the part that checks for duplicate usernames on the signup page is also implemented properly.

I wanted to work on my personal M1 MacBook, so I moved the entire project to my MacBook,

The problem is that the lab website works, but the login function does not work at all, and the button to check for duplicate IDs on the signup page does not work.

More specific symptoms are

When I enter my ID and password and try to log in, it says

I get a warning that the ID and password don't match and I can't log in.

If you enter a random ID and click the duplicate check button when registering, it will not work.

"Communication failure!" is displayed.

This problem did not occur at all when working with Windows.

The problem is that the log record in the console window of STS3 only contains logs related to the execution of server connection.

and no error messages are displayed.

I have no idea what source code I need to show to resolve this issue.

Which files should I modify?

It works fine on Windows, but not on Mac.

I have no idea if I need to modify anything or what the problem is.

I don't even know how to ask in this case.

The Java version is JRE 1.8.121.13 and the

Tomcat server is 8.5

STS3 version is 3.9.13.

MacOS is the most recent version of Ventura.

I honestly can't even figure out what code I should be uploading right now, so I'm starting with the entire member_login.jsp. I'm listing all the files in the project just in case, and if you need any of them to help you troubleshoot, let me know.

I'll show you everything except for private information like IPs.

The product, purchasing, message board, and news sections are not yet implemented as I'm still working on them.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6NRr.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHO0k.png)

The Korean version of that screenshot is

respectively

The ID or password is not correct.(ID나 비밀번호가 맞지않습니다.

Communication failure (통신실패)

This means that

first here is In order from top to bottom

member_login.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ include file = "../common_header.jsp"%>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function goPw(){
        
        mem.t_pw.focus();
        
    }
    function memberLogin(){
        mem.t_gubun.value = "MemberLogin";
        mem.method="post";
        mem.action="Member";
        mem.submit();
        
    }
</script>
        <div id="b_left">
            <P>MEMBER</P>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="javascript:goPage('login')">LOGIN</a></li>
                <li><a href="">ID / PASSWORD</a></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:goPage('join')"><span class="fnt"><i class="fas fa-apple-alt"></i></span> CONTACK</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div id="b_right">
            <p class="n_title">
                MEMBER LOGIN
            </p>
        
            <div class="login">
                <div class="member_boxL">
                    <h2>LOGIN</h2>
                    <div class="login_form">
                        <form name="mem">
                            <input type="hidden" name="t_gubun">
                            <div class="fl_clear"><label for="mbrId">아이디</label><input name="t_id" autofocus id="mbrId" type="text" onkeypress="if( event.keyCode==13 ){goPw()}"></div>
                            <div class="fl_clear"><label for="scrtNo">비밀번호</label><input name="t_pw" id="scrtNo" type="password" onkeypress="if( event.keyCode==13 ){memberLogin()}"></div>
                            <a class="btn_login btn_Blue" href="javascript:memberLogin()">로그인</a>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                   
                </div>      
            </div>

        </div>  

        <div id="b_bottom">
        <%@ include file = "../common_footer.jsp"%>     
        </div>  
    </div>  
</body>
</html>
```

member_join.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ include file = "../common_header.jsp"%>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function goJoin(){
        
        
        if(checkValue(mem.t_id,"Enter your ID!")) return;
    
        
        if(mem.yesId.value == ""){
            alert("this is not a valid ID.");
            mem.t_id.focus();
            return;
        }

        if(checkValue(mem.t_name,"Enter your name!")) return;

        if(checkValue(mem.t_password,"Enter your password!")) return;
    
        if(checkValue(mem.t_password_confirm,"check password!")) return;

        if(checkValue(mem.t_address, "Enter your address!")) return;

        if(checkValue(mem.t_mobile_1, "enter your mobile number!")) return;

        if(checkValue(mem.t_mobile_2, "enter your mobile number!")) return;

        if(checkValue(mem.t_mobile_3, "enter your mobile number!")) return;

        if(checkValue(mem.t_gender, "select your gender!")) return;

        

        mem.t_gubun.value="MemberSave";
        mem.method="post";
        mem.action="Member";
        mem.submit();
        
        
    }
    
    function checkID(){
        if(checkValue(mem.t_id,"ID 입력 후 중복검사하시오!!")) return;
        $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url : "MemberCheckId",
            data: "t_id="+mem.t_id.value,
            dataType : "text",
            error : function(){
                alert('통신실패!!!!!');
            },
            success : function(data){
                alert(data);
                if(data == "사용가능"){
                    
                    $("#idResult").text(data); //javscript에서 css적용하는 요소로 idResult가 id요소라 #사용
                    $("#idResult").css("color","black");
                    mem.yesId.value = mem.t_id.value;
                    
                }else if(data == "사용불가") {
                    $("#idResult").text(data);
                    $("#idResult").css("color","black");
                    mem.yesId.value = "";
                }
                
            }
        });             
    }
 
 </script>
        <div id="b_left">
            <P>MEMBER</P>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="javascript:goPage('login')">LOGIN</a></li>
                <li><a href="">ID / PASSWORD</a></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:goPage('join')"><span class="fnt"><i class="fas fa-apple-alt"></i></span> CONTACK</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        
        <div id="b_right">
            <p class="n_title">
                MEMBER JOIN
            </p>
            <form name="mem">   
            <input name="t_gubun">      
            <table class="boardForm">
              <colgroup>
                <col width="200" />
                <col width="500" />
              </colgroup>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <th><label for="id">I D</label></th>
                  <td>
                    <input name="t_id" type="text" size="10" id="id" title="id입력하세요">
                    <input type="button" onclick="checkID()" value="ID중복검사" class="checkB">
                    <span id="idResult"></span>
                    <input type="hidden" name="yesId">
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th><label for="nana">성 명</label></th>
                  <td><input name="t_name" type="text" size="8" id="nana"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th>비밀번호</th>
                  <td><input name="t_password" type="text" size="13"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th>비밀번호확인</th>
                  <td><input name="t_password_confirm" type="text" size="13"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th>지역</th>
                  <td>
                    <select name="t_area">
                        <option value="02">서울</option>
                        <option value="042">대전</option>
                        <option value="051">부산</option>
                        <option value="053">대구</option>        
                    </select>     
                  </td>
                </tr>   
                
                <tr>
                  <th>주소</th>
                  <td><input name="t_address" type="text" size="40"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th>연락처</th>
                  <td>
                    <input name="t_mobile_1" type="text" size="3"> -
                    <input name="t_mobile_2" type="text" size="4"> -
                    <input name="t_mobile_3" type="text" size="4">
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th>남여구분</th>
                  <td>
                      <input type="radio" value="f" name="t_gender" class="middleCheck" /> 여&nbsp;&nbsp;        
                      <input type="radio" value="m" name="t_gender" class="middleCheck" /> 남        
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th>취미</th>
                  <td>
                      <input type="checkbox" value="y" name="t_hobby_travel" class="middleCheck" /> 여행&nbsp;&nbsp; 
                      <input type="checkbox" value="y" name="t_hobby_reading" class="middleCheck" /> 독서&nbsp;&nbsp; 
                      <input type="checkbox" value="y" name="t_hobby_sports" class="middleCheck" /> 운동
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
            </form>
            <div class="buttonGroup_center">
                <a href="javascript:goJoin()" class="butt">JOIN</a>
            </div>  
        </div>  

        <div id="b_bottom">
        <%@ include file = "../common_footer.jsp"%>
        </div>  
    </div>  
</body>
</html>
```

MemberLogin.java

```
package command.member;

import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import common.CommonExecute;
import common.CommonUtil;
import dao.MemberDao;

public class MemberLogin implements CommonExecute {

    @Override
    public void execute(HttpServletRequest request) {
        MemberDao dao = new MemberDao();
        String id = request.getParameter("t_id");
        String pw = request.getParameter("t_pw");
        try {
            pw = dao.encryptSHA256(pw);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String name = dao.getLoginName(id, pw);
        String msg = "", url ="";
        if(name.equals("")) {
            msg = "This ID or password is incorrect.";
            url = "Member";
        }else {
            msg = name+"님 환영합니다!";//"welcome!"+name+"~!"
            url = "/furni/";
        
            String loginTime = CommonUtil.getTodayTime();
            int result = dao.setLoginTime(id, loginTime);
            if(result != 1) System.out.println("로그인 처리 최종로그인 시간 업데이트 오류");
            
            
            
            
            
            //정상동작확인이 되었으면 세션을 만든다.
            HttpSession session = request.getSession();//이후 세션 변수설정
            session.setAttribute("sessionId", id);
            session.setAttribute("sessionName", name);
            if(id.equals("manager")) {
                session.setAttribute("sessionLevel", "top");
            }
            session.setMaxInactiveInterval(60*60);
        }
        request.setAttribute("t_msg", msg);
        request.setAttribute("t_url", url);
        

    }

}
```

MemberSave.java

```
package command.member;

import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import common.CommonExecute;
import common.CommonUtil;
import dao.MemberDao;
import dto.MemberDto;

public class MemberSave implements CommonExecute {

    @Override
    public void execute(HttpServletRequest request) {
        MemberDao dao = new MemberDao();
        String id = request.getParameter("t_id");
        String name = request.getParameter("t_name");
        String password = request.getParameter("t_password");
        int passwordLength = password.length();
        try {
            password = dao.encryptSHA256(password);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String area = request.getParameter("t_area");
        String address = request.getParameter("t_address");
        String mobile_1 = request.getParameter("t_mobile_1");
        String mobile_2 = request.getParameter("t_mobile_2");
        String mobile_3 = request.getParameter("t_mobile_3");
        String gender = request.getParameter("t_gender");
        String hobby_travel = request.getParameter("t_hobby_travel");
        String hobby_reading = request.getParameter("t_hobby_reading");
        String hobby_sports = request.getParameter("t_hobby_sports");
        if(hobby_travel == null) hobby_travel = "n";
        if(hobby_reading == null) hobby_reading = "n";
        if(hobby_sports == null) hobby_sports = "n";
        String reg_date = CommonUtil.getTodayTime();
        
        MemberDto dto = new MemberDto(id, name, password, area, address, 
                mobile_1, mobile_2, mobile_3, gender, hobby_travel, hobby_reading, hobby_sports,
                reg_date, passwordLength);
        int result = dao.memberJoin(dto);
        String msg = name+"님 회원가입을 축하합니다."; //join congratulation message
        if(result != 1) msg = "회원가입 실패!"; //join failure message
        
        request.setAttribute("t_msg",msg);
        request.setAttribute("t_url", "/furni/");
    }

}
```

MemberController.java

```
package co.kr.furni;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import command.member.MemberLogin;
import command.member.MemberLogout;
import command.member.MemberMyinfo;
import command.member.MemberSave;
import common.CommonExecute;
import dao.MemberDao;

@Controller
public class MemberController {
    
    
    @RequestMapping("Member")
    public String member(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String gubun = request.getParameter("t_gubun");
        if(gubun == null) gubun = "login"; //null이면 login이라고 초기화 시킨다는뜼
        String viewPage = "";
        
        if(gubun.equals("login")) {
            viewPage="member/member_login";
            
        }else if(gubun.equals("join")) {
            viewPage="member/member_join";
            
        }else if(gubun.equals("MemberSave")) {
            
            MemberSave member = new MemberSave();
            member.execute(request);            
            viewPage="common_alert";
            
        //로그인   
        }else if(gubun.equals("MemberLogin")) {
            CommonExecute member = new MemberLogin();
            member.execute(request);
            viewPage = "common_alert";

        //로그아웃  
        }else if(gubun.equals("logout")) {
            CommonExecute member = new MemberLogout();
            member.execute(request);
            viewPage = "common_alert";
            
        //내정보
        }else if(gubun.equals("myinfo")) {
            HttpSession session = request.getSession();
            String id = (String)session.getAttribute("sessionId");
            if(id == null) {
                
                request.setAttribute("t_msg", "세션 정보가 만료되었습니다");
                request.setAttribute("t_url", "Member");
                viewPage = "common_alert";
                
            }else {
                
                CommonExecute member = new MemberMyinfo();
                member.execute(request);
                viewPage = "member/member_myinfo";
                
            }
            
                
        }
    
        
        return viewPage;
    }
    
    @RequestMapping("MemberCheckId")
    public void memberCheckId(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        MemberDao dao = new MemberDao();
        
        String id = request.getParameter("t_id");
        
        int count = dao.getIdCount(id);
        
        
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=utf-8");
        PrintWriter out = null;
        
        try {
            out = response.getWriter();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if(count == 0) out.print("사용가능"); //can do it 
        else out.print("사용불가"); //cannot do it
        
    
    }
    
}
```

file's source code

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rhx75.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/otBRS.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMp35.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gONKe.png)

Peeking into the console part of STS3, replacing the Java version with a different one, shutting down and restarting the MacBook,

I can't even get the problem to come up.

Comment: I'm not going to comment on the particular issue you're facing. I am, however, going to say this: start using Intellij. It's 2023 already. No, they're not both 'viable options and a matter of preference'. Eclipse lost the race. No, really. By a mile or so. And I should know. I was the last to use that monstrosity of an IDE at my company, a few years back. There really is no contest any longer